# if code is using "implicit boolean conversions".can valid c++03 code, break in c++11?

Tags: c++, c++11

With addition of change in c++11

change:Change: Specify use of explicit in existing boolean conversion operators
(https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4618/diff.cpp03.input.output)

can valid c++03 code break in c++11?

```cpp
struct abt {

        public:

        abt(int a, double b){}

         abt(int a){cout<<"int"<<endl;}

        abt(bool b) {cout<<"bool"<<endl;}

       abt(bool b,bool c) {cout<<"bool bool"<<endl;}

       operator bool() const { return true; } };

     int main() {

    abt is("a",3);
    if (is)
        std::cout << "success";
    if( is == true)
        std::cout << "success";

    return 0;
}
```

this valid c++03 code giving same output in c++11,output with implicit boolean conversion is also same in in c++11. Is there smthing wrong with rule ?

Comment: That change doesn't mean that _everything_ with boolean conversion operators has made them explicit. It's stating that specific classes from the standard library have had their conversions changed from implicit to explicit. So if you have code that specifically relies on `std::istream::sentinel` being implicitly converted to bool, that code breaks.

Comment: Thanks @NathanPierson,just double confirming,So no impact on code if it was valid  in c++03 and using user defined  variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if your `abt` would have only an explicit converion `if(is)` would be fine in C++11, because the condition of an `if` is a context where explicit conversions are "implicit". From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion):

> In the following contexts, the type bool is expected and the implicit
> conversion is performed if the declaration `bool t(e);` is well-formed
> (that is, an explicit conversion function such as `explicit T::operator bool() const;` is considered). Such expression e is said to be
> *contextually converted to bool*.
>
> - the controlling expression of `if`, `while`, `for`;
> - ...

What changed in C++11 is this and many implicit conversions to bool of standard types changed to explicit conversions. For example [`std::istream::operator bool`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool):

```
operator void*() const;                 (1)     (until C++11)
explicit operator bool() const;         (2)     (since C++11)
```

---

Code that was always wrong, but compiled before will now fail to compile, which is good. For example:

```
#include <iostream>

void foo(bool){}

int main()
{
    foo(std::cout);
}
```

[Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/E417GT)

On the other hand, if you wrote code like this and the implicit conversion was intentional, then your code breaks in C++11.

---

TL;DR:

This is not a breaking change for `if(is)`. If it was fine before it is fine now (whether `is` is your custom type with an conversion to `bool` or a standard type, and irrespective of wether the conversion is explicit or not).
If you rely too much on implcit conversions of standard types you might encounter one or two surprises though.

Comment: Can we find all standard types for which conversion constructor definition changed(i.e. from non explicit to explicit)

Comment: @alearner no I cannot provide you a complete list and I don't know where to find one. Though from the top of my head I am not aware of a conversion to bool in the streams that didn't change to explicit